# Best way to dynamically get column names from oracle tables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oracle, dynamically-generated

We are using an extractor application that will export data from the database to csv files. Based on some condition variable it extracts data from different tables, and for some conditions we have to use UNION ALL as the data has to be extracted from more than one table. So to satisfy the UNION ALL condition we are using nulls to match the number of columns.

Right now all the queries in the system are pre-built based on the condition variable. The problem is whenever there is change in the table projection (i.e new column added, existing column modified, column dropped) we have to manually change the code in the application.

Can you please give some suggestions how to extract the column names dynamically so that any changes in the table structure do not require change in the code?

---

My concern is the condition that decides which table to query. The variable condition is 
like

- if the condition is A, then load from TableX
- if the condition is B  then load from TableA and TableY.

We must know from which table we need to get data.  Once we know the table it is  straightforward to query the column names from the data dictionary.  But there is one more condition, which is that some columns need to be excluded, and these columns are different for each table.

I am trying to solve the problem only for dynamically generating the list columns. But my manager told me to make solution on the conceptual level rather than just fixing. This is a very big system with providers and consumers constantly loading and consuming data. So he wanted solution that can be general.

So what is the best way for storing condition, tablename, excluded columns?  One way is storing in database.   Are there any other ways? If yes what is the best?  As I have to give at least a couple of ideas before finalizing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, MNC, try this for size (paste it into a new console app):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Test.Api;
using Test.Api.Classes;
using Test.Api.Interfaces;
using Test.Api.Models;

namespace Test.Api.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITable
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Test.Api.Models
{
    public class MemberTable : ITable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class TableWithRelations
    {
        public MemberTable Member { get; set; }
        // list to contain partnered tables
        public IList<ITable> Partner { get; set; }

        public TableWithRelations()
        {
            Member = new MemberTable();
            Partner = new List<ITable>();
        }
    }
}

namespace Test.Api.Classes
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly IList<TableWithRelations> _tables;

        public MyClass()
        {
            // tableA stuff
            var tableA = new TableWithRelations { Member = { Id = 1, Name = "A" } };
            var relatedclasses = new List<ITable>
             {
                new MemberTable
                {
                   Id = 2,
                   Name = "B"
                }
             };
            tableA.Partner = relatedclasses;


            // tableB stuff
            var tableB = new TableWithRelations { Member = { Id = 2, Name = "B" } };
            relatedclasses = new List<ITable>
             {
                new MemberTable
                {
                   Id = 3,
                   Name = "C"
                }
             };
            tableB.Partner = relatedclasses;


            // tableC stuff
            var tableC = new TableWithRelations { Member = { Id = 3, Name = "C" } };
            relatedclasses = new List<ITable>
             {
                new MemberTable
                {
                   Id = 2,
                   Name = "D"
                }
             };
            tableC.Partner = relatedclasses;


            // tableD stuff
            var tableD = new TableWithRelations { Member = { Id = 3, Name = "D" } };
            relatedclasses = new List<ITable>
             {
                new MemberTable
                {
                   Id = 1,
                   Name = "A"
                },
                new MemberTable
                {
                   Id = 2,
                   Name = "B"
                },
             };
            tableD.Partner = relatedclasses;

            // add tables to the base tables collection
            _tables = new List<TableWithRelations> { tableA, tableB, tableC, tableD };
        }

        public IList<ITable> Compare(int tableId, string tableName)
        {
            return _tables.Where(table => table.Member.Id == tableId
                            && table.Member.Name == tableName)
                        .SelectMany(table => table.Partner).ToList();
        }
    }
}

namespace Test.Api
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private readonly MyClass _myclass;
        private readonly IList<ITable> _relatedMembers;

        public IList<ITable> RelatedMembers
        {
            get { return _relatedMembers; }
        }

        public TestClass(int id, string name)
        {
            this._myclass = new MyClass();
            // the Compare method would take your two paramters and return
            // a mathcing set of related tables that formed the related tables
            _relatedMembers = _myclass.Compare(id, name);
            // now do something wityh the resulting list
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // change these values to suit, along with rules in MyClass
        var id = 3;
        var name = "D";
        var testClass = new TestClass(id, name);

        Console.Write(string.Format("For Table{0} on Id{1}\r\n", name, id));
        Console.Write("----------------------\r\n");
        foreach (var relatedTable in testClass.RelatedMembers)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Related Table{0} on Id{1}\r\n",
                      relatedTable.Name, relatedTable.Id));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I'll get back in a bit to see if it fits or not.

Comment: Hi Jim, This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Actually I am trying to solve the problem only for dynamically generating columns. But my manager told me to make solution on the conceptual level rather than fixing. This is a very big system with providers and consumers constantly loading and consuming data. So He wanted solution that can be general. Thanks a lot for your help. This is exactly what I thought. But I guess I have to get more information on the system and work on the solution that is general enough to apply on any system.

Comment: don't be scared to give it a tick and answer mark as answered then :) - hope you manage to mold it to be extensible for all scenarios. seasons greetings...

Comment: Hi Jim, How to select 2 posts as answer. As I m trying to mark answer to yours and @APC. Its not allowing me to mark both as answer.

Comment: mnc - i'm not sure if you can mark both unfortunately. if you want to 'award' marks to one and mark the other as answer, then mark the closest answer and with the other one, just give it a little ^ up tick.

Answer (score 4):

A simple query like this helps you to know each column name of a table in Oracle.

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns where table_name='EMP'
```

Use it in your code :)

Comment: My concern is condition which decides which table to query. The varible condition 
Like if the condition is A, then load from tableX, if the condition 
is B  then load from TableA & tableY.we must know from which table we need to get data, 
Once we know the table its a straightforward as you suggested. 
& their is one more condition there are some columns that need 
to be excluded & these columns are different for each table so 
what is the best way for storing condition,tablename, exclude columns one way 
is storing in database are their any other ways
& if yes the best

Comment: @MNC : What I would do in thr code is to get the column names of each table involved in enums, dependently or not from the conditions, if your prefer you only load the enums needed, or you load all of them at the beginning of your code. About exclude columns and conditions, doing it in the database has a major interest, it's that you don't have to build your application again when you change your parameters. I would do it this way.

Comment: @LeGrandMere Sorry I guess I am not giving enough information. There are some variables that are further divided. Let me give an example. There are 2 varibles Id, name. for most of the queries based on the Id we determine the table name and extract data. But for some Ids we have to consider names also. Like if id is 5, then we have check name if Id is 5 and name is A, then laod table A, if Id is 5 name is B then load from tableB, tableA etc... So if we use enum on the ids, then we might miss the name condition.

Comment: I would suggest using ```ALL_TAB_COLUMNS``` which will expose all tables and columns in the database, as opposed to ```USER_TAB_COLUMNS``` which exposes only the tables owned by the current user.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are really after is designing a rule engine for building dynamic queries.  This is no small undertaking.  The requirements you have provided are:

1. Store rules (what you call a "condition variable")
2. Each rule selects from one or more tables
3. Additionally some rules specify columns to be excluded from a table
4. Rules which select from multiple tables are satisfied with the UNION ALL operator; tables whose projections do not match must be brought into alignment with null columns.

Some possible requirements you don't mention:

1. Format masking e.g. including or excluding the time element of DATE columns
2. Changing the order of columns in the query's projection
3. The previous requirement is particularly significant when it comes to the multi-table rules, because the projections of the tables need to match by datatype as well as number of columns.
4. Following on from that, the padding NULL columns may not necessarily be tacked on to the end of the projection e.g. a three column table may be mapped to a four column table as `col1, col2, null, col3`.
5. Some multi-table queries may need to be satisfied by *joins* rather than set operations.
6. Rules for adding WHERE clauses.
7. A mechanism for defining default sets of excluded columns (i.e. which are applied every time a table is queried) .

I would store these rules in database tables.   Because they are data and storing data is what databases are for.  (Unless you already have a rules engine to hand.)

Taking the first set of requirements you need three tables:

```
RULES
-----
RuleID 
Description
    primary key (RuleID)

RULE_TABLES
-----------
RuleID
Table_Name
Table_Query_Order
All_Columns_YN
No_of_padding_cols
    primary key (RuleID, Table_Name)


RULE_EXCLUDED_COLUMNS
---------------------
RuleID
Table_Name
Column_Name
    primary key (RuleID, Table_Name, Column_Name)
```

I've used compound primary keys just because it's easier to work with them in this context e.g. running impact analyses; I wouldn't recommend it for regular applications.

I think all of these are self-explanatory except the additional columns on RULE_TABLES.

- `Table_Query_Order` specifies the order in which the tables appear in UNION ALL queries; this matters only if you want to use the column_names of the leading table as headings in the CSV file.
- `All_Columns_YN` indicates whether the query can be written as SELECT * or whether you need to query the column names from the data dictionary and the RULE_EXCLUDED_COLUMNS table.
- `No_of_padding_cols` is a simplistic implementation for matching projections in those UNION ALL columns, by specifying how many NULLs to add to the end of the column list.

I'm not going to tackle those requirements you didn't specify because I don't know whether you care about them.  The basic thing is, what your boss is asking for is an application in its own right.  Remember that as well as an application for generating queries you're going to need an interface for maintaining the rules.

Comment: thanks for the answer I am planning to implement this What data structure we can use if we implement this if we want to store this in memory? or is it best to implement our own datatype? i.e. when the app loads first time, we can get the rules and corresponding tables. If we can build the sql query and store in memory which is the data structure i.e is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

MNC,

How about creating a dictionary of all the known tables involved in the application process up front (irrespective of the combinations - just a dictionary of the tables) which is keyed on tablename. the members of this dictionary would be a `IList<string>` of the column names. This would allow you to compare two tables on both the number of columns present `dicTable[myVarTableName].Count` as well as iterating round the `dicTable[myVarTableName].value` to pull out the column names.

At the end of the piece, you could do a little linq function to determine the table with the greatest number of columns and create the structure with nulls accordingly.

Hope this gives food for thought..

Comment: @Jim Sorry I guess I am not giving enough information. There are some variables that are further divided. Let me give an example. There are 2 varibles Id, name. for most of the queries based on the Id we determine the table name and extract data. But for some Ids we have to consider names also. Like if id is 5, then we have check name if Id is 5 and name is A, then laod table A, if Id is 5 name is B then load from tableB, tableA etc... So if we use dictionary then key on the ids, then we might miss the name condition.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't meaning to load the table data into the dictionary, only the meta-data (i.e. keyed on tablename with column names in the IList<>). you could i suppose create a decision tree in linq by further extrapolating the required logic into a richer value object.

Comment: Even I didnt take it as laoding table data in dictionary only the meta-data. But the condition is dependent on 2 values. That was my concern. It would be great help if u can give an example. Thank u.

Comment: Let me give a scenario. We have 3 ids and 3 names 1, A. 2,B. 3 C. 3, D When Id 1 then load data from tableAB, When Id 2 then load from tableBC, when Id is 3 then check for the name, Id 3 and name C then load from tableAB, tableBC, when Id 3 and name D then load from tableXYZ and tableYZ. Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: ok, no disrespect but that sounds like arbitary conditions, rather than logic per se (hope this doesn't come across as 'surly' - just an opinion before having a 'think' about how I would tackle this based on the latest info) :-)

Comment: Actually I was trying to make it easy to understand. I am not sure, but I try this We have 2 values type and source. Based on the type we get the table name, but for some types there are different sources and for the combination of type and source its a different table. So if we come across some particular types then we have to consider the source to get the actual table we need to load data. I hope it helps. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: MNC - no worries, taking a wee look just now... BTW - are the range of id's and conditions to run against those known in advance as per your comment above??

Comment: Yes. They are known in advance.

Comment: ok - see below for my 1st cut on this!! argh... will update in a bit as leaving for a few hours..